# What would be the human performance in recommender systems?

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, recommendation-engine, mahout-recommender, netflix

[Recommender systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommender_system) are automated algorithms that are heavily used today to predict which items a user will buy, which movie/music someone will like, etc. 
It has been popularized by the famous [Netflix prize](http://www.netflixprize.com/).

But if the recommendation algorithm was replaced by a human, what would be the typical success rate? Based on my profile information, including age, hobbies and list of preferred movies, is the machine much better at spotting the movies than I will like? Is there any study about the ability of humans to recommend other humans, maybe on different tasks?

Answer (score 1):

That's a tough questions. Generally this kinds of machine predict based on Data Mining result form previous data. These data can be so huge that human won't be able to find any patter on that data. In that case machine is far batter than human as they will implement its algorithm and  predict intelligently. But if you ask that do the machines know what is human's choice as human himself is unpredictable :) Yes there are so many researcher working on data mining, autonomous agent or human-agent teamwork. We can see some of by searching on these topics fat Google school-er. Best of luck

Comment: I agree is can be hard for a human. But still, there are people that can make recommendation relatively well. I'm thinking of bookshop employees that are recommending books to read based only on few personal questions. When I was young, I remember the video renting shop owner was great at recommending movies that were not mainstream, but personalized. I think these jobs are about to disappear (if not alread...), so it might be the right time to ask ourselves if we should really go to the fully automated world where recommendations are only machine-based.

Comment: Actually human predict something from his feelings & experiences. But machine does this only form his experiences(data history). Video shop owner has a feeling besides his experience for a particular video which can be matched with other human. But when a machine choose something it will see rating/selling rate etc. So, computer follow statics but human don't only do that. Besides, human can't follow statics as fast as a machine can. When we need something really calculative then computer is batter there. e.g. Which movie will be the popular movie is this year?